# PHP and Ajax Uploading

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This script inserts data into a table, as well as uploads an image
I want the URL from the image upload to be inserted into the column image

Another problem that I'm having is that when I put the upload portion of the form inside the other form, it refreshes the page and says that the file is not selected anymore.

Ideally I would only have one submit button, and the load bar would still work the same way, giving a dialog box saying the file was uploaded successfully and then after closing that it will submit the form into the database.

*index.php*

```
    <?php 
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '') ;
            mysql_select_db ('admin');
        }
        else
        {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $month = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['month']));
        $date = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['date']));
        $year = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['year']));
        $time = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['time']));
        $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
        $entry = $_POST['entry'];
        $image = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['myPost']));
        $timestamp = strtotime($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);
        $entry = nl2br($entry);
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $title = addslashes($title);
            $entry = addslashes($entry);
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (timestamp,title,entry,image) VALUES ('$timestamp','$title','$entry','$image')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or print("Can't insert into table.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
        header("location: index.php");
    }   
    $current_month = date("F");
    $current_date = date("d");
    $current_year = date("Y");
    $current_time = date("H:i");

    $sess_val = time(); //create a unique identifier for this upload session that will be the value of the hidden input
    $sess_name = ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); //this constant will be the name of the hidden input

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Geeky Gents</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <script>
    //simply fetch the progress of the current upload via AJAX
    function checkProgress()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //call the function to update the progress bar visually
    updateProgressBar(eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")")); //don't actually do this - it's unsafe
    }
    }
    //send the request to uploader.php with the progress parameter present
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "uploader.php?progress=<?php echo $sess_val; ?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    //this function converts the JSON object of the progress into a visual progress bar
    function updateProgressBar(response)
    {
    if(response['bytes_processed']==undefined) //this upload is finished
    {
    document.getElementById("progress-inner").style.width = "600px";
    alert("Done!");
    //we do not make another request for the progress since it's done
    }
    else
    {
    //calculate the new pixel width of the progress bar
    var new_width = Math.round(response['bytes_processed'] / response['content_length'] * 600);
    document.getElementById("progress-inner").style.width = new_width+"px";
    checkProgress(); //make another request for the progress
    }
    }
    //this function is called upon upload - it begins the progress checking
    function beginUpload()
    {
    var t = setTimeout("checkProgress()", 2000); //wait a bit to leave enough time for initial upload to be sent
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
        <a href="join.html">Join Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <p>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $current_month; ?>" name="month" id="month" />
        <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" size="2" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $current_year; ?>" name="year" id="year" />
        <input type="hidden" name="time" id="time" size="5" value="<?php echo $current_time; ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="title">*Title:</label><input type="text" name="title" name="title" size="40" /></p>
        <input type="text" name="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file" value="<?php strip_tags($_POST['myFile']); ?>" size="70" />
        <p>*Content:</p>
        <p><textarea cols="80" rows="20" name="entry" id="entry"></textarea></p>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='index.php'">
        </p>
        </form>
        <br /><br />
        <p>Image Uploader: (h x w)(150 x 750)</p>
            <form action="uploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="submit-catch">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $sess_name ?>" value="<?php echo $sess_val; ?>" />
            <input type="file" name="myFile" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="beginUpload();" />
            </form>
            <div id="progress-outer">
            <div id="progress-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <iframe name="submit-catch" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/GeekyGents/" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon/yt.png" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/GeekyGents/" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon/fb.png" /></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/GeekyGents/" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon/twitter.png" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Uploader.php*

```
<?php
session_start(); //we need to be able to access the session
if(isset($_REQUEST['progress']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) //getting the progress on an upload
{
//get the key of this particular upload - based on the passed parameter
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix").$_REQUEST["progress"];
if(isset($_SESSION[$key]))
echo json_encode($_SESSION[$key]); //make it easy for our JavaScript to handle the progress data
else //the session doesn't exist, which means the upload has already finished or has not yet started
echo json_encode($key);
}
else //initial upload request
{
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "uploads/");

    if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }
    $fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    $allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
    if (!in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
        echo "<p>Wrong file type, please use GIF JPEG or PNG</p>";
    }
    else
    {
    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) { 
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // set proper permissions on the new file
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
    }
}
}
?>
```

If you find anything else like security holes please do let me know about them as well, I'm learning.

Comment: Do not use mysql_*, do not use `htmlspecialchars` and `strip_tags` for escaping instead use prepared statements and MySQLi or PDO. $entry is not being escaped and can be used for injection.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you miss to set upload target for form, can you please give id "file_upload_form" to form and use below code.

```
function init() {

    document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; 
//'upload_target' is the name of the iframe
    }
}
window.onload=init;
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my problem enough, upload and everything is working perfectly fine, however:

I want the URL from the image upload to be inserted into the column image, by inserting the image URL into the image field that is inserted